# Single and multi factor analysis in SAS

Tags: sas, statistics, pca, anova, sas-studio

I am looking to conduct a single factor and multi factor analysis on some data I have. The issue is that I am researching the topic at the moment and I feel the weight of conflicting and unclear search engine results. Sometimes It refers to ANOVA, PCA, MCA, simple linear regression etc. etc.

I have been using proc reg and proc factor but I feel like my results are no different to a simple linear regression and the pca I am still experimenting with. I'm looking to find some way to distinguish a difference.

It's a simple request but could someone provide me with some material that is concise and explains the procedure well so that I can continue with my research.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The most useful documentation will be the SAS ones below:

- [ANOVA](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#anova_toc.htm) and [PCA](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_factor_sect028.htm) (PCA uses proc factor and proc princomp)
- Other useful links: [GLM  & ANOVA](https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/stat/chap4/sect11.htm) and  [PCA PDF Chapter1](https://support.sas.com/publishing/pubcat/chaps/55129.pdf)